# Bootstrap 4 toggler not working in custom Drupal 8 theme

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-4, drupal-8, theming

[image]I am working on putting together a custom Drupal 8 theme with the Bootstrap 4 framework. I created a standard HTML mockup with a navbar and everything works as expect including the navbar toggler.

However, when I transfer the code into my custom theme, the navbar toggler does not work. In other words, it won't expand on click. I have tried to debug this issue by taking the following actions:

1. Moving from Bootstrap CDN to local copies of CSS and JS Bootstrap files.
2. Verified that core/jquery was loaded first followed by popper.js and then bootstrap.min.js.
3. Compared my original HTML code with Drupal 8 theme rendering of code.
4. Making the data-target of the button a class not an id (something I saw as a solution to another person's similar issue).

All the above checked out with no issues. So I fail to see what is causing the toggler from not working.

Below, I am attaching my current code. If anyone spots what I am obviously missing, I would appreciate the help:

-menu.twig file:

```
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('navbar-nav')}}>
    {% else %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('navbar-nav')}}>
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('nav-item') }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url, item.attributes.addClass('nav-link').removeClass('nav-item')) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

-block menu -twig file:

```
<div {{attributes.addClass('col-sm-12 col-12').removeAttribute('id', 'block-
wrscd8menu')}}>
{% set heading_id = attributes.id ~ '-menu'|clean_id %}
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="{{ heading_id }}"{{ 
attributes.addClass('navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light').removeClass('col-
sm-12 col-12')|without('role', 'aria-labelledby')}}>
    <button {{attributes.addClass("navbar-toggler ml-auto mx-
0").removeClass("navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light").setAttribute('data-
target', '#block-wrscd8menu').setAttribute("type", 
"button").setAttribute("data-toggle", "collapse").setAttribute("aria-
controls", "block-wrscd8menu").setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false" 
).setAttribute("aria-label", "Toggle navigation")}}>
            <span {{attributes.addClass("navbar-toggler-
icon").removeClass("navbar-toggler ml-auto mx-0").removeAttribute("type", 
"button").removeAttribute("data-toggle", "collapse").removeAttribute("data-
target", "#block-wrscd8menu").removeAttribute("aria-controls", "block-
wrscd8menu").removeAttribute("aria-expanded", "false" ).removeAttribute("aria-
label", "Toggle navigation")}}></span>
    </button>

  {# Menu. #}
  <div {{attributes.addClass('collapse navbar-collapse').setAttribute('id', 
  'block-wrscd8menu').removeClass('navbar-toggler-icon')}} >
  {% block content %}
        {{ content }}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

libraries.yml file:

```
global-css:
  css:
    theme:
      css/styles.css: {} 

global-js:
  js:
    js/main.js: {scope: footer} 

bootstrap:
    version: 4.0.0-beta2
    css:
      theme: 
        css/bootstrap.min.css: {preprocess: false, minified: true}

    js:
      js/popper.min.js: {preprocess: false, minified: true, scope: footer}
      js/bootstrap.min.js: {preprocess: false, minified: true, scope: footer}
    dependencies:
      - core/jquery
```

P.S. Side question for Drupal themers that may see this: how do you prevent children from inheriting classes declared for parents? I am needing to use removeClass to deal with the issue in the interim. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add html source code of this(rendered html output of this script)?

Comment: @Znaneswar see added photo, which I assume, gives you what you were asking for.

Comment: can you please copy paste that region code

Comment: this is the code block that controls the navigation menu. the only thing beyond this is a row div one level up and a container-fluid div 2 levels up. Are you looking for something specific?

Comment: i think there is issue with Jquery. this code looks good. If possible add JS cdn files directly in header and test once.

Comment: i used a CDN originally...at least for the Bootstrap required Popper and Bootstrap.js code. That didn't work out. I'll add the JQuery to the header to test as you suggest though. I am wondering, as an alternative, explanation, whether other JS files, which come as part of Drupal 8 could be potentially negating what Bootstrap is trying to do with its code. There are literally a dozen or so such JS libraries like Modernizr, Jquery once, Jquery UI that are loaded as part of the Drupal 8 core.

Comment: Those JS files are created by your drupal 8 core and its modules. but make sure there should be only one Jquery file(version) and which should be at first and then followed by popper & bootstrap.js etc..

Comment: Moving the core jquery to the header does not fix the issue. The version is 3.2.1, which matches the Bootstrap version of Jquery. The JS files loaded by core are loaded optimized...wondering if that could be an issue...for a lack of a better idea at the moment.